# Why tab menu image has to be bigger the menu size?

Tags: html, css, image

See Example 2 from [this page](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex1/ddtabmenu.htm)

The right and left round corner images are used in this example is up to 83px height.I have tried to use 25px height right and left round corner images (tab menu height is 25px) and however the menu will be messed up.

My question is

1. Why images have to be much bigger than the actual tab height?
2. How to determine the image size?

Answer (score 0):

if you use image as a background of that element then you need this

```
.some_class
{
    height:100px; width:100px;
    background: url('close.png');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    -webkit-background-size: 100% 100%; /*  Safari  */
    -khtml-background-size: 100% 100%; /*  Konqueror  */
    -moz-background-size: 100% 100%; /*  Firefox  */
}
```

this will keep the image in your element's height and width

if you are using the image inside the element in HTML code, like

```
<div class="example"><img tag="images/someimage.jpg"></div>
```

then in css you need:

```
.example
{
   height: 100px
   width:  100px
 }

.example img
{
  width:100%
  height:100%
  here you can set up rounded borders for it too
}
```